# Generic repository based on Entity Framework 6 .1 and Sql Server Ce 4 exception. "InvalidOperationException"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to make a generic repository based on Entity Framework 6 .1 and Sql Server Ce 4, But I get an exception.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>   Additional information: The entity type TestClass is not part of the
>   model for the current context.

It is the code of my repository and Also I've attached a test project.

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DataContext context;

    private DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public Repository(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        this.context = dataContext;
        this.dbSet = this.context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> FindAllBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T FindFirstBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        this.dbSet.Add(entity);
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Initialization

```
 public class Framework
{
    public Framework()
    {
        DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new DbConfig());

        var databaseDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Test", "Database");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(databaseDirectory);
        var databasePath = Path.Combine(databaseDirectory, "Database.sdf");
        var sqlCeConnectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0}", databasePath);

        var dataContext = new DataContext(sqlCeConnectionString);
        this.Repository = new Repository<TestClass>(dataContext);
    }

    public IRepository<TestClass> Repository { get; set; }
}
```

[TestApp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwn5w469m5ww3sv/ConsoleApplication9.rar?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are using EF Code First, and there is no `DbSet<TestClass>` property defined in `DataContext` class.

*Sorry, have no possibility to check your TestApp at the moment.*